# phpBugtracker - allow backslashes in bug comments?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using phpBugtracker and I'm pretty new to php, but I would like to know how to allow backslashes in the comments. I noticed that only backslashes get striped but forward slashes stay. (I did manage to get 1 backslash to show when I put in 5)

Any help is appreciated!

```
$patterns = array(
    '/\r/',
    '/</',
    '/>/',
    '/\n/',
    '/(bug)[[:space:]]?(#?)([0-9]+)/i', // matches bug #nn
    '/cvs:([^\.\s:,\?!]+(\.[^\.\s:#,\?!]+)*)([:#](rev|r)?)?(\d\.[\d\.]+)?([\W\s])?/i', // matches cvs:filename.php, cvs:filename.php:n.nn or cvs:filename.php#revn.nn
    '/&lt;pre&gt;/',        // preformatted text
    '/&lt;\/pre&gt;/',      // preformatted text
    );
$replacements = array(
    '',
    '&lt;',
    '&gt;',
    '<br>',
    "<a href='$me?op=show&bugid=\\3'>\\1 #\\3</a>", // internal link to bug
    '<a href="'.CVS_WEB.'\\1#rev\\5" target="_blank">\\1</a>\\6', // external link to cvs web interface
    '<pre>',
    '</pre>',
    );

return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, stripslashes($comments));
```

Comment: well, you are passing it through `stripslashes`, so it's not too surprising that slashes are being stripped.

Comment: would it be as simple as: reproduction_steps = ".$db->quote(stripslashes($reproduction_steps))." 

reproduction_steps = ".$db->quote($reproduction_steps)."

I'm just trying to allow backslashes in a field called reproduction_steps

Comment: Remove the `stripslashes` and pass in just the `$comments` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! It seems to be successful so far, in my test environment, but I'll keep testing to see if it can start injecting SQL unintentionally.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I've added it as an answer

Comment: Still 1 thing that is troublesome: when the tracker repopulates the reporter form, I lose the backslashes inside the textarea (so \ gets passed into the DB, but when it gets called back, it strips the backslash out )

Comment: Instead of calling stripslashes, try replacing single slashes with double. Addslashes might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The reason the slashes are being stripped is because you are passing `$comments` through `stripslashes`. Just pass it in as-is and it should be ok. Worth doing some thorough testing to make sure that won't open up a security hole.